# Android accelerometer values inside Flash CS5

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash-cs5, accelerometer

Hey am a newbie to Android development. I need an application to test the accelerometer values on my mobile phone. I need the values on my system so that I can manipulate that info for something else.

If I write an Android application, the values will be inside the Mobile phone, which is not what I want.

I have written an app in Flash, n tested in Adobe Device Central. Only catch is that instead of simulator, I need to test it on my mobile. How do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to just get the accelerometer data and get it off the phone non-real time, you could download an app like this, https://market.android.com/details?id=pt.acoelhosantos.android.acc -- then get the file off your sd card afterwards. There are several other apps on marketplace that will let you see and or record the data from sensors real time. Or if you are feeling crafty and want to learn a bit about sensor access programming, feel free to read up on the android SensorManager and SensorEventListener, no permissions in android manifest needed! If you plan to implement your own app I recommend handling listening to each sensor in its own thread, you can read up on Threads with Handlers or AsyncTasks for that. I implemented my sensor code as a service that spawns async threads personally, and received updates via intent with broadcastreceiver. This is a great project to learn about threads, intents, services, etc. if you are interested. Good luck!